# in swipe tabs how to keep the tab no reopen when u swipe more then one tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

i have swipe tabs with 3 tab i first tab will have web view with Facebook other got text only , now if i swipe from first tab to the second then come back to the first its good but if i swipe to the 3rd tab when i go back to the first tab the web view will reload again , how can i stop that

this is my code 
home.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
ViewPager Tab;
TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
            new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                    actionBar = getActionBar();
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                    }
            });
    Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
         public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }};
        //Add New Tab
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Android").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("iOS").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Windows").setTabListener(tabListener));

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewPager has a method setOffscreenPageLimit() that determines how many pages to retain when they go off screen.

try increasing the page limit. For example:

Tab.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);